# Draw a line under a figure that match the figure lentgh

Tags: graphics, rules, lengths, decorations

I am using a line under a figure to make it more aesthetic. I am having a problem with matching the line length with the figure length.

Here's a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\decoRule}{\rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}} % New command for a rule to be used under figures
\begin{document}

Example of how I define and use DecoRule.

\begin{figure}[tbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{cover}
\decoRule
\caption[Cover]{This is a cover.}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\widthof` from the calc package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\decoRule}[1]{\rule{#1}{.4pt}} % New command for a rule to be used under figures

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

Example of how I define and use DecoRule.

\begin{figure}[tbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{example-image-a}
\decoRule{\widthof{\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{example-image-a}}}
\caption[Cover]{This is a cover.}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

I added `mwe` so that I could compile without your specific figure.

It would probably be most efficient to make a newcommand that wraps the whole thing, instead of just making the decoline a command and having to retype the figure.

Comment: You don't actually have to load the `mwe` package to use the images provided by it, as long as it's installed you're good to go with `\includegraphics{example-image}`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to couple the length of the rule with the figure width. Here it is done via `\setbox` but you can also do it with `\settowidth`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\newcommand{\decoRule}{\rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}} % New command for a rule to be used under figures
\newcommand\decoImage[2][]{%
  \setbox0\hbox{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}
  \parbox{\wd0}{%
    \copy0
    \hrulefill
  }
}
\begin{document}
Text
\begin{figure}[tbp]
  \centering
  \decoImage[scale=0.4,angle=30]{example-image-a}
  \caption[Cover]{This is a cover.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]